# String Tokenizing Into Individual Variables

Tags: c++, string, c++11, tokenize

I have an array of sets of numbers and words that are all put together in one string like so:

`"hello jane 7 14 1993 female"`

How do I tokenize a string like this and similar strings to assign each word to a separate variable if each word separated by a space bar is to go to its own variable like so?:

```
 string greeting = "hello"
 string name = "jane"
 string month = "7"
 string day = "14"
 string year = "1993"
 string gender = "female"
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string str = "hello jane 7 14 1993 female";

std::string greeting, name, month, day, year, gender;

std::istringstream(str) >> greeting >> name >> month >> day >> year >> gender;
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab2fae0e394b6571)